# Agreement of the past participle with the auxiliary avoir

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Let's, for instance, take this sentence:

> Mes frères ne m'avaient pas respecté jusqu'à ce que je sois devenue la directrice de commerce.

If the narrator, I, is a woman, should *respecté* add an **e** (*respectée*) because **m'** (meaning **me**) is before the verb?

I have read this [rule](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/agreement-with-direct-objects/) but am not sure how it applies in the case of **me**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to agree with the direct object. The phrase must be:

> Mes frères ne m'avaient pas respecté**e** jusqu'à ce que je sois devenue directrice commerciale.